# How do you perform a recursive SQL query eliminating duplicates from the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I have table containing the Identity (UnitID), Postcode, No Of Bedrooms, and Property Valuation
I need to find out what Properties with the same Postcode and same No of Bedrooms have different Property Valuations.

[Sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIhuy.png)

```
SELECT  'B' AS GroupID
        ,U.UNITID AS [Unit ID]
        ,A.postcode AS Postcode
        ,U.NOOFBEDROOMS AS [No Of Bedrooms]
        ,U.PROPERTYVALUE1999 AS [Property Valuation]
        ,A.postcode + ' | ' + CAST(U.NOOFBEDROOMS AS varchar(3)) AS CheckID
INTO #A_PropertyValue1999
FROM    landingax.hpmunitstaging U
LEFT JOIN LandingCRM.hsl_asset A ON U.UNITID = A.reference
WHERE   U.CONTROLSTATUSID = 'Active'
AND     U.PROPERTYVALUE1999 IS NOT NULL
```

I then ran this query to check for differences (concatenating Postcode and No Of Bedrooms as an ID to join the two):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 'A' AS GroupID
        ,U.UNITID AS [UnitID A]
        ,A.postcode AS Postcode
        ,U.NOOFBEDROOMS AS [No Of Bedrooms]
        ,U.PROPERTYVALUE1999 AS [Property A Valuation]
        ,A.postcode + ' | ' + CAST(U.NOOFBEDROOMS AS varchar(3)) AS CheckID
        ,#A_PropertyValue1999.[Unit ID] AS [UnitID B]
        ,#A_PropertyValue1999.[Property Valuation] AS [Property B Valuation]
FROM    landingax.hpmunitstaging U
LEFT JOIN LandingCRM.asset A ON U.UNITID = A.hsl_reference
INNER JOIN  #A_PropertyValue1999 ON A.postcode + ' | ' + CAST(U.NOOFBEDROOMS AS varchar(3)) = #A_PropertyValue1999.CheckID
```

The problem is I get multiple rows for the same exception because when Property A and Property B differ it returns Property B and Property A as an exception - the following table may explain the issue more clearly:

[sample results showing duplicates in result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ADT.png)

[Example of what I am attempting to avoid - line 1 is duplicated in line 2, only UnitID is switched round](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vsrS.png)

Apologies, I do not know how to put tables of data into a more readable format:

**Sample Data**

```
Unit ID Postcode    No Of Bedrooms  PROPERTYVALUE1999   CheckID
U034    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1
U037    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1
U036    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1
U995    ZZ1 1ZZ 2   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 2
U032    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1
U031    ZZ1 1ZZ 2   45000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 2
U033    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1
U035    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1
```

**Current results from my query:**

```
UnitID A    Postcode    No Of Bedrooms  Property A Valuation    CheckID UnitID B    Property B Valuation
U031    ZZ1 1ZZ 2   45000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 2 U995    85000
U032    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U034    85000
U032    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U037    85000
U033    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U034    85000
U033    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U037    85000
U034    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U032    65000
U034    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U033    65000
U034    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U035    65000
U034    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U036    65000
U035    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U034    85000
U035    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U037    85000
U036    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U034    85000
U036    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   65000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U037    85000
U037    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U032    65000
U037    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U033    65000
U037    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U035    65000
U037    ZZ1 1ZZ 1   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 1 U036    65000
U995    ZZ1 1ZZ 2   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 2 U031    45000
```

**Example of what I am trying to avoid - 2 rows for the same exception, only difference is Unit A becomes Unit B and vice versa**

```
UnitID A    Postcode    No Of Bedrooms  Property A Valuation    CheckID UnitID B    Property B Valuation
U031    ZZ1 1ZZ 2   45000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 2 U995    85000
U995    ZZ1 1ZZ 2   85000   ZZ1 1ZZ | 2 U031    45000
```

Comment: I find it hard to relate the queries and the resultset. Would you please provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text?

Comment: Hi GMB, I have added the sample tables but as images because I do not know how to add tables as text, sorry!